# Cordova - Hide keyboard without lose focus

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm building an application that use a device with external keyboard (barcode scanner). So, my primary keyboard is the scanner.

I have some text input and when input has focus, i dont want to see the keyboard (i read from the scanner).

In other cases, i will provide a specific button to show/hide the keyboard.

How i can hide keyboard without lose the focus?

Looking on github i found a plugin to show/hide keyboard.. but without luck.. this is the code:

```
@Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    Activity activity = this.cordova.getActivity();
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    View view;
    try {
        view = (View)webView.getClass().getMethod("getView").invoke(webView);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        view = (View)webView;
    }

    if("show".equals(action)){
        imm.showSoftInput(view, 0);
        callbackContext.success();
        return true;
    }
    else if("hide".equals(action)){
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        callbackContext.success();
        return true;
    }
    callbackContext.error(action + " is not a supported action");
    return false;
    }
```